# angular: how to handle code provided by attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

As an example of what I want, consider the following example

```
<select ng-options="option.text for option in options"></select>
```

In my directive I want to use something similar to ngOptions, because I need to create a list

For example, assume I have a directive barFoo, called as follows:

```
<bar-foo options="options"></bar-foo>
```

with a template/html as follows:

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="option in options" ng-bind="option.text"></li>
</ol>
```

What is needed to change all this into a call like

```
<bar-foo options="option.text for option in options"></bar-foo>
```

The main reason I need this is because I don't know the property name holding the label text (in this case it is **text**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provided a fiddle and see whether this helps. Instead of passing in "options.text for option in options", I set it up such that you pass the "options" array and then the field you want. I assumed the field will be set up as a variable; if it hard-coded, then you can just do field='someFieldName' instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/y376K/1/

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app='testApp'>
    <div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
        <bar-foo options='options' field='{{optionsField}}'></bar-foo>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [
        {
            text: 'Node.js rocks my socks',
            language: 'Node.js',
        },
        {
            text: 'Angular is hot',
            language: 'Angular.js',
        },
        {
            text: 'Backbone.js is mmmm',
            language: 'Backbone.js',
        }        
    ];
    $scope.optionsField = 'text';
})
.directive('barFoo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            options: '=',
            field: '@'
        },
        template: '<ol><li ng-repeat="option in options" ng-bind="option[field]"></li>'
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by parsing the attribute. The other solution would be to pass it as two attributes (see the other answer)

You should probably use a regexp for this, but I coded this quickly:

```
app.directive('barFoo',function($parse) {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},
  templateUrl: "template.html",
  link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
    var splitOptions = attrs.options.split(' for ');
    scope.fieldName = splitOptions[0].split('.')[1];
    var repeatExp = splitOptions[1];
    scope.valueName = repeatExp.split(' in ')[0];
    var collectionName = repeatExp.split(' in ')[1];
    scope.values = $parse(collectionName)(scope.$parent);       
  }
 };
});
```

See [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KUUkdBUmRdcFQKclCVWU?p=preview)

Comment: I checked the angular code and saw that they have a very impressive regex to split that string. I don't think this is the preferred solution!

Comment: I tried using that regex first but didn't quite understand what was happening. This is just to show the basic idea.